# Elastic search query containing '!' in regexp query doesnt match against any results

Tags: regex, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl, elasticsearch-dsl-py

Elastic search below query doesn't return any results:

1.)    `{"query":{"regexp":{"field_name":".*f04((?!z).)*"}}`

Why a query like above doesn't return any result?

I'm expecting results like this : 
`['f00bar', 'f04bar', 'f04barbuh', 'f04ba']`

whereas below one returns:

2.)    `{"query":{"regexp":{"field_name":".*f04((?!z).)*.*"}}`

Results returned by this : `['f04bar', 'f04barbuh', 'f04ba', 'f04baz']`

I know that 2nd query returns result because of .* at the end, is there anything wrong with `'!'` in the regexp, it should be something else? how do we use `!` as the part of regexp to specify `ba` should not be followed by `z`.

Answer (score 0):

The `regexp` query is run against the index which contains the analyzed version of the underlying data. By default the `standard` analyzer is used which splits text into words (just alphanumeric), removes everything else (here is where `!` will get removed) and then lowercases everything.

To see exactly what's happening you can use the `_analyze` API, to modify that process either map that field as `keyword` or specify a different `analyzer`.

Comment: My fields are mapped as keyword only like below:  {
  "field_name1": {
    "type": "keyword"
  },
  "field_name2": {
    "type": "keyword"
  },
  "query": {
    "properties": {
      "regexp": {
        "properties": {
          "field_name1": {
            "type": "keyword"
          },
          "field_name2": {
            "type": "keyword"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}